# Is there a way to extract a SAPC4C textvalue property with Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-data-factory, odata, azure-synapse

I try to pull data out of SAPC4C (Cloud for Customer) with Azure Synapse Analytics. Unfortunately I ran into a problem with extracting TextValue field.

When I try to extract the AnswerCollection one of the available fields is the 'TextValue' field. This field then contains the property 'content'. See printscreen below.
[Prinscreen Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Xuk.png)

When I try the same in Synapse Analytics, I do not see these fields. Is there a way to make these fields available in Synapse?

[Available fields in Synapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXTLE.png)

In Synapse I make use of the 'SAP Cloud For Customer' connector.

I already tried several options:

- change the connector to oData.
- change of the oData query: tried the $expand & $select options